# jQuery .hover with elements under it

Tags: jquery, hover

please check out: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/usaxZ/1/)

What I want to get is a working hover with every of the 4 squares. For example if the first blue square is hovered and I scroll the mouse a little bit to the right until it enters the green square (which is under the hovered blue square) the green square should get hovered.

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 4):

Try this [jsFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/usaxZ/6/) in which I only changed the JavaScript.

Comment: Different thing, congratulations for you.

Comment: Sorry I was too quick :( Your solution does only work if the color is attached to the outer div. I need to have the boxes changed in size and position them absolute.